# Can I store an Object inside a button in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, object, button

I am creating Buttons dynamically in my code, is there a way I can store a custom object in my button so I can use it when I press this button ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Consider using the command pattern and bind a command to the button's [`Command` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.command.aspx) and use the [`CommandParameter` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.commandparameter.aspx) to store your object.

When the button is clicked the `Execute` method of your command will be invoked using the `CommandParameter` (containing your object) as parameter.

It would be good to know the scenario you are working at. Generating XAML by code is a sign you may be on the wrong track as long as you are not building custom controls.

Most things can be accomplished via data bindings and repeater controls such as listboxes, menus, datagrids, etc. Are you familar with the MVVM pattern?

Comment: Im using that too, but i need to store a unique object to each button

Comment: @raym0nd: There's also the [`CommandParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.commandparameter.aspx), you see. It presumably exists exactly for that use-case.

Comment: Why do you need to store an object? If you use the Command pattern you may create custom commands by implementing the simple `ICommand` interface. This class can wrap all functionality required and may be initialized using your object.

Comment: @Zebi: While it might be a good idea to give some peripheral advice this hardly should be the focus of your answer (as it is bolded), instead i would recommend to incorporate a mention of the CommandParameter in your answer as that actually answers the question of how to store an object in the button.

Answer (score 21):

You *could* use the [`Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx) for that, needs to be cast when getting the object though.

Comment: @H.B.: Yes, but what _should_ the OP do :-)  One can do that, but using that approach ignores the widely recommended patterns for WPF (and most modern) GUI development.

Comment: @EricJ.: I would recommend the [commanding way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) of doing things, i suppose, it's less of a mess.

Answer (score 2):

You also *could* use an [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of options to do that declaratively (through binding to `Tag` or other non-used fields) or not, but one less intrusive way if you are creating buttons dynamically would be to simply create a `Dictionary<Button, T>` mapping which stores needed object for each button.

Comment: In that case you might as well create an attached property which basically does the same thing.

Comment: Which is actually better than using Tag or any other fields, because using them is limiting, not very much, but still.

Comment: True, the Tag is a bit of a bastard, without much of a reason for existing. Possibly for convenience? (I now actually added my comment as another answer :P)

Answer (score 0):

you can also inherit Button and put your class over there...